# What is an interpreter output files generated (like .obj)

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter

hey there my question is that what is the output of interpreter. for example in compiler the output file is .obj and .exe but what about interpreter what is the out put i tried to look for it in the internet but end up with nothing. If any one have any idea please help.

I also search here and i did not found the answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as 'output of the interpreter'. The interpreter executes compiled bytecode, or possibly source code, and its output is whatever the program being interpreted outputs. It doesn't produce yet another object file.

Comment: so you mean if the source code is in python. the interpreter will be .pys

Comment: Don't tell me what I mean. I mean what I said. Nothing more. If you have another question please ask it. What you describe is self-evidently the output of a compiler, not an interpreter.

Comment: sorry sir i did not mean anything i was just asking. yes it is for compiler the .obj and .exe. but i was just asking for interpreter what is output file generated.

Comment: @Ghezlan There will be no output file.